# Why is a question about the squarity of c in E=mc2 so bad received?

Tags: discussion

In [$E=mc^2$ why is it $c^2$ and not just $c$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17404/e-mc2-why-is-it-c2-and-not-just-c) is this question posted. I'm really interested in the answer but why is this question not very broad answered and even bad received. Is it really just a matter of accepting.....?

Comment: The equation can't even work dimensionally with just a single c. The question is probably badly received because the poster obviously didn't put much effort into it. But, in general, asking "Why is this question well/badly received?" is not really a question we can resolve here on meta  because votes are anonymous.

Comment: To somebody who has studied physics, this just is not a question to ponder. As pointed out, it just can't be a solitary $c$. Period, full stop.

Answer (score 7):

Though I haven't looked at that question recently I can offer at least three reasons that I have for not liking it. Some of the voters might have had similar reactions.

1. The suggestion is dimensionally inconsistent which makes it ["Not even wrong"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong). This is a skill that should be mastered early in a first course in physics.
2. It is totally unmotivated. One can do experimental work based on simple-minded fitting to experimental results, but that poster is not making his (or her) suggestion in the context of data; so it's pure whiteboard theory. Theory is done by reasoning from things already known and perhaps extending them in a consistent way. But the poster either hasn't done that or hasn't shown the first indication that (s)he did.
3. The question is un-researched in a really extreme way. We already had questions on this site addressing where the $c^2$ comes from including the one offered by Qmechanic in the comments. And basic issues in relativity have been addressed at the popular level for the last hundred years or so.